# Return Type of Oracle Trunc Function

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jasper-reports

```
select trunc('11.01') from dual
```

**Output** : 11

What is its datatype in jasper report am getting as BigDecimal.
Is there any work around to get that as string.

Comment: Uh, well, you can just `.toString()` that `BigDecimal`...

Comment: @fge probably these are finantial amounts and a SUM function will be applied in the footer of the report...

Comment: Thanks for  all of your support.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle's `TRUNC` function works on dates and numerics only, so Oracle is casting your `11.01` to numeric. To have Oracle return it as a string, do this:

```
select to_char(trunc('11.01')) from dual;
```